# an exception is unhandled in inset query object reference is not set to the instance object VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, razor

This is my code in vb.net , when i pass the insert query to the SQL server from VB.net i got exception at query that object reference is not set to the instance object,
in sql fileds are allow null and ID is auto incrrament.
one of my companion said that use record set and tell the condition somthing like that but i have totally no idea about record set in New in VB.net,
please help me, what should i do,

Collapse | Copy Code

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class MaintenanceTask
    Dim cn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Sub connect()
        cn = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Fleet Maintainance;Integrated Security=True")
    End Sub
    Sub lockall()
        cBx1.Enabled = False
        cBx2.Enabled = False
        tBx1.Enabled = False
        tBx2.Enabled = False
        tBx3.Enabled = False
    End Sub
    Sub unlockall()
        cBx1.Enabled = True
        cBx2.Enabled = True
        tBx1.Enabled = True
        tBx2.Enabled = True
        tBx3.Enabled = True
    End Sub
    Sub setall()
        cBx1.Text = ""
        cBx2.Text = ""
        tBx1.Text = ""
        tBx2.Text = ""
        tBx3.Text = ""
    End Sub
    Sub updatecombo1()
        Call connect()
        Dim cd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT [Name],[NameID] FROM [RepairName] order by [Name]", cn)
        Dim adp As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cd)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        adp.Fill(ds)
        'ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
        cBx1.DisplayMember = "Name"
        cBx1.ValueMember = "NameID"
        cBx1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    End Sub
    Sub updatecombo2()
        Call connect()
        Dim cd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT [RepairType],[RepairTypeID] FROM [RepairType] order by [RepairType]", cn)
        Dim adp As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cd)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        adp.Fill(ds)
        'ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
        cBx2.DisplayMember = "RepairType"
        cBx2.ValueMember = "RepairTypeID"
        cBx2.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    End Sub
    Sub updatecombo3()
        Call connect()
        Dim cd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT [Service],[ServiceID] FROM [Service] order by [Service]", cn)
        Dim adp As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cd)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        adp.Fill(ds)
        'ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
        cBx1.DisplayMember = "Service"
        cBx1.ValueMember = "ServiceID"
        cBx1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If cBx1.Enabled = True Then
            Dim str As String = "insert into MaintenanceTask (MainID, TypeID, PartCost, LaborCost, Total) values (" & (cBx1.SelectedValue.ToString()) & ", " & (cBx2.SelectedValue.ToString()) & ", " & CInt(tBx1.Text) & "," & CInt(tBx2.Text) & "," & CInt(tBx3.Text) & ")"
            Call connect()
            Dim cd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(str, cn)
            cd.Connection.Open()
            cd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cd.Connection.Close()
            MsgBox(" New Task is added successfully ")
            Call lockall()
            Me.Close()
            Call IssueWorkOrder.listView2load()

        Else
            MsgBox(" Task is not added Try again ")

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        AddService.Show()
        AddService.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
        RadioButton1.Text = "Preventive"
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
        RadioButton2.Text = "Repair"
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.Click
        Call updatecombo3()
        Label3.Text = "Service"
        cBx2.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.Click
        Call updatecombo1()
        Call updatecombo2()
        Label3.Text = "Repair"
        cBx2.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: why are you not disposing your connection?

Answer (score 0):

Your primary problem is your insert string. 
You don't check if the values of the combo are valid or not and call ToString on an NULL (Nothing) in VB item

```
   Dim str As String = "insert into MaintenanceTask (MainID, TypeID, PartCost, " & _
                       "LaborCost, Total) values (" & (cBx1.SelectedValue.ToString()) & _
                       ", " & (cBx2.SelectedValue.ToString()) & ", " & CInt(tBx1.Text) & _
                        "," & CInt(tBx2.Text) & "," & CInt(tBx3.Text) & ")"
```

If cBx1.SelectedValue is NULL you can't call a method (ToString) on a NULL object and this is the NullReferenceException received.
However you have a more serious problem called [Sql Injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) (Please read the article)

```
   Dim str As String = "insert into MaintenanceTask (MainID, TypeID, PartCost, " & _
                       "LaborCost, Total) values (@main, @tp, @cost, @labcost, @tot)"

    Dim cd As New SqlCommand(str, cn)
    cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@main", if(cbx1.SelectedValue == null, DBNull.Value, cbx1.SelectedValue.ToString)
    cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tp", if(cbx2.SelectedValue == null, DBNull.Value, cbx2.SelectedValue.ToString)
    cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cost", Convert.ToInt32(tBx1.Text))
    cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@labcost", Convert.ToInt32(tBx2.Text))
    cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totale", Convert.ToInt32(tBx3.Text))
    cd.Connection.Open()
    cd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cd.Connection.Close()
    MsgBox(" New Task is added successfully ")
    Call lockall()
    Me.Close()
    Call IssueWorkOrder.listView2load()
```

Other problems are the conversion to integer of a textbox.
If the input is not a valid numeric value you get an error, you need a bit of error handling before 
The connection object is a scarce resource and you should be sure to close when done. Your code lacks error handling and in case of error yuor connection is never closed.

Comment: the connection is not closed and disposed even if there is no error